# I thought I was never / I thought I would never

Tags: grammar, word-usage

“Just two weeks ago I thought I was never going to meet him”
“Just two weeks ago I thought I’d never meet him”

Which one of these two sentences is correct? If they’re both correct, what’s the difference between them?

Comment: will(would) is about someone's willingness to do while be going to is something planned.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, both are correct. Difference is:

> Just two weeks ago I thought **I’d** never meet him

This one doesn't imply has that something you thought will never happen has not already happened in the past 2 weeks. Might be it has happened, might be it hasn't.

Like: Just two weeks ago I thought I’d never dance. You might have danced yesterday. We can't tell from this are you expecting for that to happen or has it already happened in this last 2 weeks and you are simply stating that in some point in time before you didn't believe it will happen.

> Just two weeks ago I thought **I was** never **going to** meet him

This one imply that something you thought it will never happen, did not happen in the meantime, but you now (unlike before) expect it will happen in future.

Like: Just two weeks ago I thought I was never going to dance. You expect to dance tomorrow or in  x amount of time, but you for sure have not danced in last 2 weeks. Your intent is to simply say you now expect it to happen unlike at certain point in past when you didn't expect it to happen .

At least that is what I read from it.